# is there a way where i can remove this on the terminal?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

c:; cd 'c:\Users\maven.aria\Desktop\javaprogram'; & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe' '--enable-preview' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-cp' 'C:\Users\maven.aria\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\0f3a3007105f5c536af5d6be5f698785\redhat.java\jdt_ws\javaprogram_cc305553\bin' 'firstprog'

Comment: That is what runs your program...

Comment: is there a way so it wont show it every time i run the code???

Comment: why do you care?

Comment: ive seen others that runs java without this popping up on vscode, im just wondering tho...

Comment: Put it in a script file, and the user can run the script. On MS-DOS, that would go into a .bat file. Windows might still use .bat files. On Unix, it might go into a .sh file.

Comment: you can create a key binding that sends a command to the terminal, but you have to take care of the current directory and starting the debugger, and that is what you see, so no need to do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use [**Code Runner**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner), I wonder if this can meet your needs.

After the extension is installed, use the `Run Code` option to execute the code, and the code will be output in the **OUTPUT** panel.

[image]

Add a configuration in *settings.json* to get only result output.

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

[image]

The following configuration allows **TERMINAL** to output the results when using **Code Runner**, but the command will be displayed.

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

[image]

*Of course, it is better to use the official extension to run the program. The program runs incorrectly because coderunner may not be able to read the project structure.*